# Limit relating to the Laplace transform

Tags: limits

In the book I am reading on differential equations, the author introduces the Laplace transform of a function by first giving some important limits to know. Here is one of them:

$$\lim_{x\to \infty}x^ne^{-sx}=0$$

for $s>0$ and $n\in \mathbb R$

My first guess as to how to solve this would be L'Hopital's rule. Again, my question is:

*How do you prove that this limit equals $0$?*

Comment: Your first guess is right.  As Shia Labeouf would say, just do it!

Answer (score 0):

We have
$$\log\left(x^ne^{-sx}\right) = n\log x-sx\stackrel{x\to\infty}{\longrightarrow}-\infty. $$
Since the exponential function is continuous, it follows that
$$\begin{align*}
\lim_{x\to\infty} x^ne^{-sx} &= \lim_{x\to\infty}e^{\log\left(x^ne^{-sx}\right)}\\
&= e^{\lim_{x\to\infty}\log\left(x^ne^{-sx}\right)}\\
&= 0.
\end{align*}$$